# Remove Host from Foreman

Tags: foreman, theforeman

n Foreman 1.12 I deleted a VM from the VMware web client, but cannot delete its record from foreman.

I got the below error:

Error: Failed to destroy a compute VMware (VMware) instance
*************: ERF56-4248 [Foreman::FingerprintException]: The remote system presented a public key with hash *********** but we're expecting a different hash. If you are sure the remote system is authentic, go to the compute resource edit page, press the 'Test Connection' or 'Load Datacenters' button and submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try un-associating the host first.

To un-associate a host in Foreman, click the host you want to delete. There should be a button at the top right that reads `Unassociate Host`. Then, you should be able to delete the host.

Comment: Many Thanks, 
It is called "Disassociate Host" in my version